# Python reading CSV from File and Sending Auto Message

Tags: python

i tried to implement auto blast whatsapp using library from [here](https://github.com/kavinsharma/python-bulk-whatsapp-message-automation-excel)

and seems that im hving problem with string concatenation
here is the leads.csv data im using

```
LeadNumber,Message
91_98888888647,None
91_98888888647,Message Sent by Whatsapp Bot 1
91_98888888647,Message 2
91_98888888647,Testing 3
91_98888888647,Message 4
91_98888888647,Message Sent by Whatsapp Bot
```

and here is the code i implement

```
import pyautogui as pg
import webbrowser as web
import time
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("leads.csv")
data_dict = data.to_dict('list')
leads = data_dict['LeadNumber']
messages = data_dict['Message']
combo = zip(leads,messages)
first = True

for lead, message in combo:
    time.sleep(4)
    web.open("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+lead+"&text="+message)
    if first:
        time.sleep(6)
        first=False
    width, height = pg.size()
    pg.click(width/2,height/2)
    time.sleep(8)
    pg.press('enter')
    time.sleep(8)
    pg.hotkey('ctrl', 'w')
```

and this is the error message i am getting

```
C:\Users\ursab\PycharmProjects\WaBlast\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/ursab/PycharmProjects/WaBlast/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ursab\PycharmProjects\WaBlast\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    web.open("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+lead+"&text="+message)
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

until now i have no idea because the first column is str in excel
do i need to convert ?
any help or advise will be appreciated.

im expecting the python code reading the strong concatenation and running the program.

Comment: str(lead) could help you. Also, you should check that you have the correct value in your lead column. If somewhere your strings with "_" are interpreted as integers, somehting is wrong.

Comment: data_dict['LeadNumber'] refers to an iterable containing objects of type *int*. An f-string would have been useful here. Also, why all the sleeps? You may have determined empirically that this works but it's not likely to be reliable or to perform well